# Caliburn.Micro, MVVM pattern: CanExecute command doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

This is my View:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Label>Customer name:</Label>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Customer.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="136"/>
    <Button x:Name="UpdateClick">Update</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
private Customer customer;
public Customer Customer
{
    get { return customer; }
    set { customer = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Customer); }
}

public bool CanUpdateClick 
{ 
    get 
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.Name))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true; 
    } 
}

public void UpdateClick()
{
    //...
}
```

And this is my model:

```
private string name;
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Name); }
}
```

So I have UpdateClick method and it works perfectly. I also have CanUpdateClick property, but it doesn't work and I don't know why? Button on the UI should be disabled when the textbox is empty. Please help!

Comment: That's because the notify property changed is only notifying that `Customer.Name` has changed not the `CanUpdateClick`. Name is a property within the customer class so would have to tap into the propertychanged of the customer in order to get that notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of the `Customer` class (since you seem to be subclassing `PropertyChangedBase`) and call `NotifyOfPropertyChanged(() => CanUpdateClick)` when the `Name` property is changed:

```
// in your view model
// i'm assuming here that Customer is set before your view model is activated
protected override void OnActivate()
{
    base.OnActivate();
    Customer.PropertyChanged += CustomerPropertyChangedHandler;
}

protected override void OnDeactivate(bool close)
{
    base.OnDeactivate(close);
    // unregister handler
    Customer.PropertyChanged -= CustomerPropertyChangedHandler;
}

// event handler
protected void CustomerPropertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Customer.Name))
    {
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanUpdateClick);
    }
}
```

Or, you can just create a `Name` or `CustomerName` property in your view model to bind to and a) use `Customer.Name` as your backing field or b) use a normal backing field then just set `Customer.Name` when updating:

In your view:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CustomerName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="136"/>
```

And here's how you implement option a in your view model:

```
public string CustomerName
{
    get { return Customer.Name; }
    set
    {
        Customer.Name = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(); // CallerMemberName goodness
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanUpdateClick);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I prefer the second proposal of yours. But then I don't know how to implement ContentPresenter in the View that shows a validation message?